# Do linear or logistic regression models adjust for the correlation between groups?

Tags: logistic, correlation, standard-error, linear

Suppose I have an ANCOVA model with a continuous dependent variable, $y$, and a four-group predictor (control/reference, treatment A, B and C), coded as 0,1,2 and 3.

$$
y = \beta_0+\beta_1 \text{dummy}_1+\beta_2 \text{dummy}_2+\beta_3 \text{dummy}_3+\epsilon
$$

Can we safely assume that the standard error (SE) of the mean differences (SEs of the beta coefficients; each treatment vs control) are adjusted for the correlation created because all treatment groups share the same reference group?

Cheers!

Jacob

Comment: Yes and correlations between parameter estimates will also be properly handled.  For example one $\beta$ will be correlated with another, but differences in $\beta$s that do not have a treatment group in common will be uncorrelated.

Comment: Thank you so much, Frank. Very clear explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes and correlations between parameter estimates will also be properly handled. For example one  will be correlated with another, but differences in s that do not have a treatment group in common will be uncorrelated. Author of the response: Frank Harrell Jan 6 at 14:12